# HTML Back button that disappears after clicking it once?

Tags: html, angularjs

i need a Back Button that disappears, looked at ngdisabled from AngularJS but quite the beginner.

```
<button onClick="history.go(-1);" >Go back</button>
```

Already got the back button, and i want to disable it after its been clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<button onClick="history.go(-1);this.disabled=true;" >Go back</button>
```

Comment: it says you can tick in 4 minutes!

Comment: i also then want to re-enable it after my pdf-link is clicked, ive simply put onClick="this.disabled=false" in the <iframe> but it didnt work? @AliZia

Comment: See this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901452/how-do-i-disable-a-text-box-within-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<button ng-click="goBack" ng-disabled="backDisabled">Go back</button>
```

click function:

```
$scope.goBack = function(){
  $window.history.back();
  $scope.backDisabled = true; // use $rootScope to access everywhere of app.
}
```

Comment: Yes this also works, do you know how to re-enable it after i click something else?

Comment: you can add it on ´´´$routeScope´´´ and set false as re-routing page.

Comment: I dont understand sorry?

Comment: look that https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

and if you vote my answer you'll make me happy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your button is contained by an Angular-Controller, a more Angular-approach to this problem would be something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.GoBackInHistory()" 
            ng-disabled="ctrl.isBackButtonDisabled">
        Go back
    </button>
</div>
<script>
    angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('controller', controller);

    controller.$inject = ['$window'];
    function controller($window) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.isBackButtonDisabled = false;
        vm.GoBackInHistory = GoBackInHistory;

        function GoBackInHistory() {
            $window.history.back(); //or $window.history.go(-1);
            vm.isBackButtonDisabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Wow thanks the code looks exactly like what i need i think, but its not working!

Comment: What exactly is it not doing? I made a plunkr and it all seems to be working: http://plnkr.co/edit/EN439PF7exLVCny6a4s9?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but i want the button to become available again as soon as i open a pdf file again, get me? So when im viewing a pdf, i can press back button and go back to all pdfs in a list, and the button becomes disabled, and as soon as i click on another pdf i want the button to become available again so i can go back again.

Comment: If the event of opening another PDF is also managed by the same controller, you could simply flip the variable once the user clicks on a pdf. If it is not managed by the same controller, you could use an $scope.$broadcast or $scope.$emit event.